# Get the value of textbox after refreshing the form

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have a continuous form that has the property that has some fields.
When I click a button on the form a Requery is processed on the form which results in updated value of some textboxes (these are not enabled, i.e. read only).

What I'm trying to do is to get the value of one of the textboxes in the form after Requery.
How do I do that?
I've tried using the Current event to get the value after the requery (refresh) but it's not working. Is there any other event that can do the work?

Comment: What do you mean by a continuous form? If you update the textbox then the value is changed immediately. You may not _see_ that change unless you refresh your textbox if the update is in the middle of some processing. Can you post some code?

Comment: Are you building your UI in Access or in VB6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution..
The problem was that the value of the field I was trying to get the value of comes from adding 2 values (a + b)

and so the solution was updating the field before saving its value to a different variable...

Answer (score 1):

Just use the name of the field.  For example, after the requery, use `msgbox [FieldName]`.

Comment: I tried, but I still get the old value... for example: txtValue is the name of my textbox.. txtValue = Hello, Requery, MsgBox txtValue --> I get Hello, then the form refreshes showing me Hellow World in txtValue

Comment: I think there's a more basic problem here.  Can you edit your question and add a step-by-step of how this form works? A code snippet would help too.

Comment: @newb: poweruser said to access the field directly but in your response, you are clearly accessing the contents of a textbox, not a recordset field.